# Delete duplicates in list of dictionary depending on criteria

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I only found questions where people wanted to delete duplicates but not depending on a criteria which includes the value of the keys.

Lets say I have a List containing dictionaries

```
myList = [
  {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-03-11 22:28:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'}
]
```

now I want to remove the duplicate dictionaries where the keys have the same value, e.g., `version` has the value `v1` and only keep the most current one but I don't know that the value is `v1` so I have to check for duplicates in `version` without knowing the value. After finding the duplicates I want to compare the date in `update` and choose the latest one and remove the duplicates due to this criteria. I can not guarantee that the latest one is the last entry, like it can be seen in `myList` that the second entry for `v1` is the latest one, not the third one.

Resulting in

```
myCleanedList= [
  {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'},
  {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
myList = [
    {"version": "v1", "updated": "2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00"},
    {"version": "v1", "updated": "2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00"},
    {"version": "v5", "updated": "2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00"},
    {"version": "v1", "updated": "2020-03-11 22:28:00+00:00"},
    {"version": "v7", "updated": "2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00"},
]

out = {}
for d in myList:
    out.setdefault(d["version"], []).append(d)

out = [
    sorted(v, key=lambda k: k["updated"], reverse=True)[0] for v in out.values()
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00'}, 
 {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'}, 
 {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'}]
```

Comment: Works fine but what if I have different keys and the same value? E.g. 
`myList = [
    {"version": "v1", "updated": "2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00"},
    {"versioning": "v1", "updated": "2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00"},
    {"version": "v5", "updated": "2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00"},
    {"version": "v1", "updated": "2020-03-11 22:28:00+00:00"},
    {"version": "v7", "updated": "2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00"},
]`
Is there still a way to find the duplicates in `version` AND `versioning` combined so I have the same result as before and keeping the key `version`?

Answer (score 0):

Code with always sorted 'version' in any input order:
(input order was changed to 'version' 1-7-5 instead original 1-5-7)

```
myList = [
    {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'},
    {'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'},
    {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00'},
    {'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'},
    {'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-03-11 22:28:00+00:00'}
]

out = {d["version"]: d for d in sorted(myList, key=lambda k: k["updated"])}
print(*sorted(out.values(), key=lambda k: k["version"]), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
{'version': 'v1', 'updated': '2020-08-24 17:37:00+00:00'}
{'version': 'v5', 'updated': '2019-08-30 11:42:00+00:00'}
{'version': 'v7', 'updated': '2020-06-17 22:15:00+00:00'}
```